Are both of the sentence grammatically correct?
Pardon me, it's a basic question.

(A) I still remember the physics rules my father taught me.
(B) I still remember the physics rules my father taught to me.


According to OALD, yes. Both "teach sth to sb" and "teach sb sth" are grammatically correct.

But (A) is  much more idiomatic.

@KateBunting  I think that may vary by dialect.  I have heard B quite a lot.
